QGIS Print composer - the same legend
I have several items in print composers.
All items have same objects/legends.
Is it possible to set compositions to change legend in one object will change legend in other compositions?

I don't understand - why did you create several layouts that have exactly the same objects? What problem are you trying to solve?

Each layout is controlled by different atlas. Some legends are the same. Now, I have to make changes to every layout.

In the future you might use dynamic elements in Atlas layouts.

add context, examples, illustration and explain more precisely what's you tried, then we can understand you problem

You can copy and paste legends between print composers.

Yes, I know. But changing legend in one print composer will not change legend in others. Is there a way to do this? without copying again?

Not to my knowledge.
